# Problems setting proxy on HttpClient

Tags: .net, http, proxy, dotnet-httpclient, webproxy

In my C# application I'm trying to send an HTTP request to an external company outside of our firewall.  When I use the below code, I'm getting back an error that the remote site has forcibly closed the connection.  I'm assuming I'm doing something incorrectly with the proxy setting but I'm not sure what.  Our proxy does not require authentication.

```cs
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()) {
    handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.my.domain.com:911");

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler: handler, disposeHandler: false)) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "...");

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://...", content);
```

I've printed out the encoded JSON that gets sent and if I just do things manually via `curl` the request goes right though, so I'm sure that my URL, bearer token and JSON are all correct.

Comment: You mean curl with the proxy?

Comment: Yes. I have the http_proxy env var set

Comment: Don't you need to set UseProxy = true for your HttpClientHandler?

Comment: Argh!  So simple, @ZagNut.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments, the proxy variable must be set to ***true***. I would like to emphasize it for other users having the same problem.

As this is mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ca-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.useproxy?view=netframework-4.8).

I give a small example of how to use it in a [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976042/httpclientfactory-create-vs-new-httpclient) like class:

```
private HttpClient ClientFactoryV02()
{
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler(){ UseProxy = true};
    clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy("address-of-proxy");

    var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("uri");
    }
}
_createHttpClient = () => ClientFactoryV02();
```

Credits to: ZagNut, Ben.