# What is the purpose of the HttpClientFactory (System.Net.Http.Formatting)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient, httpclientfactory

There is a lot of talk on the Internet about `HttpClient`, `IHttpClientFactory`, DI, socket exhaustion problem, etc.

Can someone explain to me why the [`HttpClientFactory class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995280(v%3Dvs.118)) (from *System.Net.Http.Formatting* assembly) is needed and its methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClientFactory.Create vs new HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976042/httpclientfactory-create-vs-new-httpclient)

Answer (score 4):

`System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory`, which is shipped with the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client), is just a helper to create a `HttpMessageHandler` with a pipeline of multiple `HttpDelegatingHandler` objects. Its `Create` method [literally does this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/ebef5b7d821b64ed5c48765d0caf6ce8a9bcfaf5/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientFactory.cs#L41-L45):

```
public static HttpClient Create(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
{
    HttpMessageHandler pipeline = CreatePipeline(innerHandler, handlers);
    return new HttpClient(pipeline);
}
```

And the [`CreatePipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt174864(v=vs.118)) sets up a single `HttpMessageHandler` that wrapps all the passed handlers into a single pipeline, so that they get executed in order.

This `HttpClientFactory` has little to do with the newer [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) that’s part of the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http). That one is what all the “buzz” is about and how you should ideally create HTTP clients in the future.

Comment: I'm not using .NET Core 2.1+ so don't have access to `IHttpClientFactory`. Is it better then to use `HttpClientFactory.Create()` instead of using `HttpClient`?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner If you only want a standard HttpClient in a legacy .NET Framework application, then you can just create a static `HttpClient` that you reuse yourself. `HttpClientFactory.Create` is only really useful if you need to customize the handler pipelines in some way.