# Typed HttpClient vs IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Is there any difference between the following 2 scenarios of setting up HttpClient?

Should I prefer one to another?

Typed client:

```
public class CatalogService 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient) {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> Get() {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync();
        ....
    }
    
    public async Task Post() {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync();
        ...
    }
}
// Startup.cs
//Add http client services at ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
```

IHttpClientFactory:

````
public class CatalogService 
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _factory;
    
    public CatalogService(IHttpClientFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> Get() {
        var response = await _factory.CreateClient().GetAsync();
        ....
    }
    
    public async Task Post() {
        var response = await _factory.CreateClient().PostAsync();
        ...
    }
}
// Startup.cs
//Add http client services at ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddHttpClient();
```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClientFactory.Create vs new HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976042/httpclientfactory-create-vs-new-httpclient)

Comment: @Julian, nope, since it's about old HttpFactory

Comment: could you summarize what conclusions did you do?

Answer (score 17):

Versioning:

- **UPDATED at 07 Oct 22** by adding named and typed client

---

I think the biggest difference reveals itself when you look at them from the consumption point of view.

#### Typed client

You will receive a `HttpClient` instance, which might have been decorated with some resilient strategy against transient failure and with some default values. You might even receive a client where the `BaseUrl` is already set.

So, this approach can be particularly useful if you need to hide a REST API client behind a strongly-typed service layer.

#### Named client

This technique can shine when you need several instances from a specific client or when you need several different clients. If you have registered several different clients with different names then you can retrieve them easily via a single API.

So, this approach could be useful if you need to call different downstream systems and you need to aggregate their results.

#### Named and typed client

There is a third option which is a combination of the above two. You get the strongly-typed API of the typed clients and the unique naming capability of named clients.

This can be particularly useful when you want to use the same typed client API against different domains (like there is a primary and a secondary site). Or you want to have slightly different Polly policies (different downstream systems might need different timeout settings) ...

[Here I have detailed how can you create and use the different clients.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73715343/13268855)

#### Good to read articles

- [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)
- [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests)
- [IHttpClientFactory with named Clients](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore)
- [IHttpClientFactory with typed clients](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/ihttpclientfactory-patterns-using-typed-clients-from-singleton-services)
- [IHttpClientFactory with Polly](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-using-polly-for-transient-fault-handling)

Answer (score 5):

IMO, I will go with passing `HttpClient`. The reasons are,

1. **KISS Principle** - What `CatalogService` really needs is a `HttpClient`. The service does not care about how to get a client.
2. **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)** - Say tomorrow you have to keep two instances of `CatalogService` to send requests to two different endpoints,

   - You can pass in a `IHttpClientFactory` and implement routing inside `CatalogService`, but that breaks SRP.
   - Or, you can create a `CatalogServiceFactory`. That factory gets `IHttpClientFactory` passed in and implement routing inside. That is also known as *Separation of Concerns*.

Answer (score -1):

Having abstraction (i.e. `IHttpClient`) is far better and more praised by the community. It allows you to assign `HttpClient` as well as your custom-written `IHttpClient` without ever changing `CatalogService`.

This is very critical point when creating large systems as your dependencies on concrete implementations decreases, so does the maintenance costs.

Furthermore, using abstractions allows showing what usage was actually intended and reduces the possible distractions. One example:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void UsefulMethod();
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public float variable1;
    public float moreBurden;
    public float thisIsNotRequiredAtAll;

    public void UsefulMethod() {}
    public void AnotherMethod() {}
    public void MoreNoiseMethod() {}
}

public class MyService
{
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public MyService(MyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void MyOnlyMethod()
    {
        _myClass.UsefulMethod();
    }
}
```

In this case, you are only using single method, but your service can access tons of unnecessary information, thus distracting from the goal. And to create `MyService`, its creator must be able to create instance of `MyClass`.

Now image `MyService` is written like

```
public class MyService
{
    private IMyInterface _myInterface;

    public MyService(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }
   
    public void MyOnlyMethod()
    {
        _myInterface.UsefulMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, the purpose of `_myInterface` is clear - you only need a specific subset of methods. `MyService` only has access to that single method and isn't distracted by all the possible implementation details.

Comment: Although all this maybe true, my gut feeling is you missed the point of the ops question

Comment: Yup, my mistake, I've missed it's `IHttpClientFactory` not `IHttpClient`...