# Do I need to add all HttpClients?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

If I use `_httpClientFactory.CreateClient()` in a singleton (no name for the client, I set it up when I use it)

Should I add/specify an empty `services.AddHttpClient();` at startup or is that not necessary?

Comment: Well, `services.AddHttpClient()` registers `IHttpClientFactory` with the container... I wonder why you haven't simply tried this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only specify empty `services.AddHttpClient();` on startup. You could pass it `name` parameter if you want to configure "specific" `HttpClient` that you will later call by name (for example add base address or headers). Otherwise `IHttpClientFactory` will give you not configured one (like calling `new HttpClient()`)

For example:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyApiClient").ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["MyApiUrl"]);
});
```

and later calling factory like:

```
_httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyApiClient");
```

will give you `HttpClient` with configured base address.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now better. We have a lot of named + T-typed `AddHttpClient()` in the project, and that's why I don't need in this case the empty one, because any AddHttpClient<x>(xxx) will do - to give access to the HttpClientFactory by the DI. So that's why it worked either way for me when I tested with or without the empty one.

Comment: @steb There are actually 4 kinds of client that you can be register via `AddHttpClient`. Here you can read more about them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286062/typed-httpclient-vs-ihttpclientfactory/64313603#64313603

Answer (score 0):

The services.AddHttpClient(); in your startup class is used to configure an IHttpClientFactory instance,
which is then used to create and manage named HttpClient instances.

If you are creating an instance of HttpClient directly with _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(), without specifying a named client,

what i suggest is you don't need to add the services.AddHttpClient(); line in the Startup class.

FACT:
This line is necessary only if you plan to use the IHttpClientFactory to create named HttpClient instances.

for More visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0