# HttpClients and default AddScoped service

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

Considering these topics:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561368/648723

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67067195/648723

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045301/648723

They said: **keep an instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of your application**

But when we create a new `Blazor` application, in `Program.cs` file, the default `HttpClient` registered as this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = "MyUrl"});
```

1. Why Microsoft didn't use `AddSingleton` for `HttpClient`?
2. Is it necessary to use `IHttpClientFactory` instead of `HttpClient`?
3. If I want to use Multiple `HttpClient` in my `Blazor` application, How can I register and inject intended `HttpClient` (With intended base URL) in my code?

Thanks

Comment: #2 yes, because it actually manages the lifetime of the HttpClient beyond a single request scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topics you link say to create an instance of HttpClient **per API you're connecting to** which is an important difference.
`AddSingleton` would only make sense if you're sure your application will only ever connect to one specific API.

You can instantiate an HttpClient just fine, but the factory pattern contains a lot of optimization on when to create a new instance or to reuse an existing instance. It also prevents you from running out of sockets which will happen if you have too many HttpClient instances at once. See here for more: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

This post shows how to define multiple named HttpClients for different URLs: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore

Comment: _"`AddSingleton` would only make sense if you're sure your application will only ever connect to one specific API."_  only if base address is specified, OP can remove that.

Answer (score 1):

> They said: keep an instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of your application

While it was a preferred approach for quite a long time but it has its drawbacks - for example handling DNS changes (though based on this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18348#issuecomment-415845645) it can be worked around by changing [`SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.pooledconnectionlifetime?view=net-6.0) property to something else from the default `InfiniteTimeSpan`)

> Why Microsoft didn't use `AddSingleton` for `HttpClient`?

I would argue this question should be addressed to Microsoft

> Is it necessary to use `IHttpClientFactory` instead of `HttpClient`?

In theory - no, but it is recommended approach to handle the complexities of http calls and `HttpClient` lifetime, because most of them should be handled by the `IHttpClientFactory` and in general you will not need to care.

> If I want to use Multiple HttpClient in my Blazor application, How can I register and inject intended HttpClient (With intended base URL) in my code?

It can be easily achieved with `IHttpClientFactory` by setting it up in the DI either with [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#named-clients) or [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typed-clients).

Comment: Please be aware that [named](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L47) and [typed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L274) clients are registered as `Transient`.

Comment: @PeterCsala not quite - caching works at the *handler* level, not the HttpClient instance itself. HttpClientFactory will create new HttpClient instances as needed and initialize them with cached handlers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think Peter is right. Do you have reference for what you said? Thanks

Comment: I didn't say he's wrong - HttpClientFactory creates new instances than can be discarded. It's the *handlers* that are cached by default for 10 minutes then recycled. As for reference, I had to check the source back when HttpClientFactory was new and the docs .... a bit lacking, to find how to constrain connections to a bad external service

Comment: [Here's the code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L117). When a new HttpClient is needed, the factory creates a new instance with a handler coming from `_activeHandlers`.

Comment: Each cached handler entry has [an expiration timer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L232) that [removes the handler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L207) from `_activeHandlers`

Comment: The reason I had to check this was I was calling a badly written service with an equally bad sticky load balancer. When the service failed, the balancer would keep sending my requests to the same failed instance.