# HttpClient pipelining HTTP GET requests to ServiceStack API

Tags: servicestack, dotnet-httpclient, http.sys, http-pipelining

First, I have ServiceStack as my server which provides RESTful HTTP API.

Here is an example.

```
public void GET(XXXXXRequest request)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Then I use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to access it.
As it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently),  `HttpClient` is thread-safe for most of its methods to sending HTTP GET requests over the same TCP connection.

So I have a singleton instance of HttpClient as below

```
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler()
{
    AllowPipelining = true
});
```

Then I use the following test code to send the request one after previous's response

```
await _httpClient.SendAsync(request1, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
await _httpClient.SendAsync(request2, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
await _httpClient.SendAsync(request3, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
```

In [smart sniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html),  I do see the requests are sent in one connection and it goes like:

```
Client -> Request1
Client <- Response1
Client -> Request2
Client <- Response2
Client -> Request3
Client <- Response3
```

Now I change the code to fire-and-forget mode as below.

```
_httpClient.SendAsync(request1, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
_httpClient.SendAsync(request2, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
_httpClient.SendAsync(request3, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
```

So that the requests are sent without waiting for previous reponse and I **expect** the requests & response go like below

```
Client -> Request1
Client -> Request2
Client -> Request3
Client <- Response1
Client <- Response2
Client <- Response3
```

This is [HTTP pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) and quite good for performance.

[image]

But from my test, I see 3 connections are established for each of the HTTP GET request and it does not work as I expected.

Regarding the `AllowPipelining` proeprty, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.allowpipelining(v=vs.110).aspx) says

> An application uses the AllowPipelining property to indicate a
>   preference for pipelined connections. When AllowPipelining is true, an
>   application makes pipelined connections to the servers that support
>   them.

So, I suppose `HttpClient` does support pipelining, and the problem is located in ServiceStack? Is there some options in ServiceStack to enable HTTP pipelining?

Answer (score 2):

Pipelining is done at a very low level, below IIS even (in the `http.sys` kernel mode driver). While I'm afraid I can't explain the behavior you're seeing, I can confidently say that ServiceStack is not on the hook for supporting it. It's an HttpHandler, whose only concern is how to process a request and return a response.

Comment: I am using self-host service `AppSelfHostBase` instead of IIS, I assume it is done via `http.sys` and `HttpListener` internally?

Comment: Yes. ServiceStack's [listener](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/HttpListener/HttpListenerBase.cs) uses System.Net.HttpListener internally.

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple `await` operators, they are run one after another, so HttpClient is only given one request at a time, and therefore can't use pipelining.

You can use Task.WhenAll() to run multiple tasks in parallel:

```
var responses = await Task.WhenAll(
    _httpClient.SendAsync(request1, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead),
    _httpClient.SendAsync(request2, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead),
    _httpClient.SendAsync(request3, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead));

var response1 = responses[0];
var response2 = responses[1];
var response3 = responses[2];
```

Notice that only the `Task.WhenAll` is awaited