# Would a singleton HttpClient slow down with a large number of requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have a `HttpClientWrapper`, called `CarInformationClient`

```
public class CarInformationClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CarInformationClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<CarInfoResponse> GetCarInfoAsync(string customerReference)
    {
        var request = new CarInfoRequest
        {
            CustomerReference = customerReference
        };

        var response = await _//send data with httpclient
        //do something with the response
    }
}
```

And I am registering it as a singleton with Windsor

```
Component.For<HttpClient>().LifestyleSingleton()
```

As `HttpClient` is supposed to be reused across calls to the same host, is this singleton implementationg going to slow things down if a large number of clients simulatenously call `GetCarInfoAsync` as there is only ever one instance of `HttpClient`? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143162/is-a-singleton-a-good-way-of-instantiating-a-httpclient) but it doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: You'll definitely want to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194054/is-async-httpclient-from-net-4-5-a-bad-choice-for-intensive-load-applications, as it discusses some important things (like setting the default connection limit)