# Get web page using HtmlAgilityPack.NETCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, html-agility-pack

I used the `HtmlAgilityPack` for work with html pages.
Previously I did this:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("necessary node");
```

but now i need to use the HtmlAgilityPack.NETCore where `HtmlWeb` is absent.
What should i use instead `HtmlWeb` to have the same result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `HttpClient` as a new way to interact with remote resources via http.

As for your solution, you probably need to use the `async` methods here for non-blocking your thread, instead of `.Result` usage. Also note that [`HttpClient` was meant to be used from different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178220/213550) starting from .Net 4.5, so you should not recreate it each time:

```
// instance or static variable
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// get answer in non-blocking way
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
{
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
        // read answer in non-blocking way
        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(result);
        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Your nodes");
        //Some work with page....
    }
}
```

Great article about async/await: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by @StephenCleary | March 2013

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio code with netcoreapp1.0.
Ended up using HtmlAgilityPack version 1.5.0-beta5 instead.

Remember to add:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
```

I did it like this:

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient(); 
HttpResponseMessage result = await hc.GetAsync($"http://somewebsite.com"); 
Stream stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); 
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(stream); 
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='whateverclassyouarelookingfor']");
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and it's working. Is this a good way to solve my problem?

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(result);
            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Your nodes");
            //Some work with page....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting for me. Why we cannot use await for : client.GetAsync(url)

Answer (score -1):

You can use HttpClient to get the content of the page.

Comment: I'm looking for it but can't find. Can you show me how use it?

Comment: Did you mean something like this?
`WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFile(url, path);`
i would like to work with file without saving.