# HttpClientFactory Memory Leak

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, httpclientfactory

In my c# console app (.net 4.6.1), I am required make API calls (Get/Post/Put/delete) etc to random endpoints. The details of the url, payload etc comes from a database table.  The console app gets the httpClientFactory instance as shown below

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
```

For each record I get from the table, I call a method to make an API call. To that method I pass the httpClientFactory.  In that method, I am creating and using HttpClient as follows.

```
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
//set headers
//make api call, for ex  var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(apiTask.URL, content);
//Return resposne
```

I am no where disposing of httpClient.  As I see the memory usage, it keeps on increasing and I don't see it going down even after hours.

I followed the following article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Am i using it right?. Should I be using the "using(httpClient)"

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to instantiate new `HttpClient` per request, you can use share one instance between all of them since `HttpClient` is designed to be reusable and thread safe.

check [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client), it is also woth to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently)