# Using Singleton Instance inside Static method

Tags: c#, .net, static, thread-safety, singleton

I have a call with a static method in my web application. This method uses a singleton instance of a different class. This singleton instance is basically an HttpClient to make some api requests.

Currently I don't have any mechanism to automate multi-user testing on this. Are there any consequences of this approach? I know a usual static method is thread safe if we are not using static variables inside it. But I am not sure how it behaves in case of singleton.

```
public static class API
{
    private static System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient;

    public static System.Net.Http.HttpClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return httpClient ?? (httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient());
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetData(string id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await 
    API.Instance.GetAsync(string.Format(requestURL, id));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid threading issues, you need to at least implement the singleton in a thread-safe manner. This [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) by Jon Skeet describes some ways how a singleton instance can be created in a thread-safe way. In addition, you should make sure that the methods of the singleton can either handle parallel requests or use `lock` to synchronize the calls.

The problem with using the Singleton in the static method is also one of object-oriented design. Having a singleton and using it in lots of places of your application is convenient, but has its downsides:

- A fellow developer cannot see on the first look that your methods rely on a singleton instance. It is a hidden dependency.
- Also, you cannot easily change the instance in cases where you need a different behavior, e.g. in tests.

So I'd propose to think about whether the singleton is really necessary or whether you can inject it as a parameter into the methods where it is needed:

```
public static async Task<string> GetData(API api, string id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await 
    api.Instance.GetAsync(string.Format(requestURL, id));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

You could change the method to be an extension method that you can call like:

```
var result = await API.Instance.GetData("123");
```

You just have to add a `this` to the signature:

```
public static async Task<string> GetData(this API api, string id)
{
  // ...
}
```