# HttpClient DocumentClient What Happens With Different Threads. Azure Functons

Tags: c#, httpclient, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I read in an article about HttpClient/DocumentClient that it can be best practice to create a singleton for apps and inject it into object so that underlying resources are not exhausted by continued re-creating.How does this work? If an HttpClient is being accessed by various threads and making simultaneous calls to possibly different endpoints I can't see how this can work.

I read this

```
   https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc
```

with interest. If I have an Azure Function making use of a DocumentClient calling cosmosDb how should I use the DocumentClient? Should it be a static instance?

I have my Azure function set up like this. I presume a new instance of DocmentClient is being created with every request which under high load could cause resource problems.

```
[FunctionName("MyGetFunc")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [CosmosDB("ct","ops", ConnectionStringSetting ="cosmosConn")] 
    DocumentClient docClient,
    ILogger log)

    //use docClient here...
    {
```

Comment: HttpClient is thread safe. Apart from that, why not call different URLs? HttpClient isn't HttpWebRequest which can only be used for one URL, in fact, just one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the DocumentClient part of your question see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db?tabs=csharp#customize-a-documentclient-and-reuse-it-between-executions

They talk about the different scenarios. So yes, if you have many Function invocations, I would use one static instance - which is also thread-safe.

```
private static DocumentClient client = GetCustomClient();
private static DocumentClient GetCustomClient()
{
    DocumentClient customClient = new DocumentClient(
        new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDBAccountEndpoint"]), 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDBAccountKey"],
        new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
            // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30
            }
        });

    // Customize PreferredLocations
    customClient.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.CentralUS);
    customClient.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.NorthEurope);

    return customClient;
}

[FunctionName("CosmosDbSample")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
```

Answer (score 2):

> If an `HttpClient` is being accessed by various threads and making simultaneous calls to possibly different endpoints I can't see how this can work.

Why? The `HttpClient` is thread-safe which means that it can be used from several concurrent threads simultaneously.

[Is HttpClient safe to use concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently)

Comment: Thanks. How can one instance call different endpoints simultaneously?

Comment: @PaulStanley why shouldn't it? Are you confusing it with HttpWebRequest perhaps? Or with WCF's proxies that only called one endpoint?

Comment: @PaulStanley: By for example calling its `GetAsync` method with different arguments from two different threads.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I wasn't getting it confused with HttpWebRequest I was just not understanding the asynchronous nature of the Class.

Comment: @PaulStanley it has nothing to do with asynchronous communication. It's thread safe. In any class, any method that *doesn't* depend on modifying shared data can be used from multiple threads without locking. If you want to see what's going on under the covers you can [inspect the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET Core, please also refer to [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

> `HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an `HttpClient` class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. That issue will result in `SocketException` errors. Possible approaches to solve that problem are based on the creation of the `HttpClient` object as singleton or static, as explained in this [Microsoft article on HttpClient usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient).
>
> But there’s a second issue with `HttpClient` that you can have when you use it as singleton or static object. In this case, a singleton or static HttpClient doesn't respect DNS changes, as explained in this issue at the [.NET Core GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224).
>
> To address those mentioned issues and make the management of `HttpClient` instances easier, .NET Core 2.1 introduced a new `HttpClientFactory` that can also be used to implement resilient HTTP calls by integrating Polly with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CosmosDB("ct","ops", ConnectionStringSetting ="cosmosConn")] 
    DocumentClient docClient,
```

That is using the **Cosmos DB Binding**. The Binding **does not create multiple instances** of the DocumentClient, it will **create one and reuse it in all executions**.

You can check the source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Bindings/CosmosDBClientBuilder.cs.

It calls `GetService` and obtains the DocumentClient instance for that particular connection string if one already was created in a previous execution.

Similarly to maintaining your own static/Lazy DocumentClient (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#documentclient-code-example-c).