# HttpClient usage in polly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

Wanted to verify if `HttpCLient` instance should be created outside method passed to polly for `ExecuteAsync`, or in?

My current usage varies between the two options and I am not sure which is the correct one?

Also, if it incurs some drawbacks, or possible memory leaks, etc. ?

Get:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()) { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeOutSec) };

var httpResponse = await AuthenticationOnUnauthorizePolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    UpdateClientHeader(client, correlationId);
    return await client.GetAsync(url, token);
});
```

Post:

```
var httpResponse = await AuthenticationOnUnauthorizePolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()) { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeOutSec) })
    {
        UpdateClientHeader(client, correlationId);
        WriteNetworkAccessStatusToLog();
        return await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
});
```

The policy used here:

```
AuthenticationOnUnauthorizePolicy = Policy
     .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(reposnse => reposnse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
     .RetryAsync(1, onRetryAsync:
     async (response, count, context) =>
     {
         _logger.Info("Unauthorized Response! Retrying Authentication...");
         await Authenticate();
     });
```

Appreciates any comments on the code above.

Is there a correct way?

Do I need to use the `Context` to get the client again, or is my usage okay?

---

Update:

Authenticate method:

```
public virtual async Task Authenticate()
{
    // lock it - only one request can request token
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isAuthenticated, 1, 0) == 0)
    {
        var result = new WebResult();
        var loginModel = new LoginModel
        {
            email = _settingService.Email,
            password = _settingService.Password
        };

        var url = ......
        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        try
        {
            var stringObj = JsonHelper.SerializeObject(loginModel);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(stringObj, Encoding.UTF8, HttpConsts.JsonMediaType);

            using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()) { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeOutSec) }
            )
            {
                UpdateClientHeader(client, correlationId, useToken: false); // not token, we need new one
                using (var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
                {
                    var sReader = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    await HandleRequest(result, sReader, httpResponse, correlationId, url, "result");
                }
            }
            if (result != null && !result.HasError)
            {
                _loginToken = result.Token;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error
        }
        finally
        {
            _isAuthenticated = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Update client headr method:

```
if (_loginToken != null &&
                !client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Token"))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", _loginToken );
            }
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(HttpConsts.JsonMediaType));
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the code of `Authenticate` and `UpdateClientHeader` as well?

Comment: Updated with methods.

Comment: don't put a HttpClient in a using block. [It doesn't work that way](https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc). Use a static instance.

Comment: How do you get the `_loginToken` inside `UpdateClientHeader`?  How is it updated?

Comment: @JHBonarius Isn't static instance dangerous to use? Can't the client dispose after timeout or some error state, and I'll have to manage clients? create, remove, update and dispose them?

Comment: No, not for `HttpCient`. It's the suggested use as specified in [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient)

Comment: @PeterCsala I have edited the code to reflect this, sorry about that.

Comment: @JHBonarius Then what about thread safety, with only one instance?

Comment: Google it. e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178252)

Comment: @o_w Just to make sure that my understanding is correct: You want to have a `HttpClient` that is used against an API which requires the presence of a token. That token can expire / invalidated that's why you want to have a mechanism to request a new / refresh the token. You want to handle that with Polly. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @PeterCsala All of this coe was already present in the project before me. I am trying to understand if our use of HttpClient is correct, that is all. The Authentication part is less important in this context.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you, I'll check having my own pool of HttpClients for use across all requests.

Comment: @o_w If your question is concerned only about the HttpClient then please remove the  `polly` tag and add `dotnet-httpclient` instead. I would also encourage you to read this excellent article (old but gold): [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @PeterCsala It still relates to Polly, since I don't know if including the client's creation in the return call method is crucial or not.

Comment: @o_w As it was already suggested you should not need to create a new HttpClient per request. You can and should reuse that client, which issues requests against the same domain. In other words you should have a client per domain.

Comment: @PeterCsala What constitutes a domain in my case? GetAsync is one and SendAsync is one? Or is it by topic?

Comment: @o_w If you issue requests against `http://subdomainA.domain.com` and `http://subdomainB.domain.com` then they are under the same domain. If you issue requests against `http://domainA.com` and `http://domainB.com` then they are under different domains. The http VERB does not matter.