# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core

I've been using .NET 6 and for the first this error happen.

I have an application that uses a lot of background workers in the same HTTP client, and sometimes this error happens:

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I tried to use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. But I wasn't successful.

Follow my http client configuration:

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(Queries.Sne.Serpro.Api.Infracoes.InfracaoQuery.CLIENT_KEY, (provider, client) =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fake-link/");
});
```

Observation:

I use this httpclient asynchronously, so there are several tasks using this same client, however, when I execute my application with a single Task, this error didn't happen.

Comment: The error clearly indicates that the request was forcibly closed by the *remote* host. Are you sure the remote does not have any built in precautions to rate limit or block multiple concurrent requests coming from the same IP address or something?

Comment: I think the point is with async. Some calls may hang-up in a deadlock so after the timeout IIS kills the task. 
Check your async/awaits or use logs to put an ID on every call by tracking start/end time to check this hint.

Comment: @nbokmans great question, I have no information about the remote host, I will implement a delay between the request to check it.

Comment: Not all HttpClient methods are thread safe, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178252/6092856 ; If you need multiple threads to contact the remote host, consider using an HttpClientFactory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory

Comment: @ArwynFr oh thanks, but in this case the error happens in an 'SendAsync'.